# FormatMessage not allowed?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Looking at the documentation for [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says `Minimum supported client
Windows XP [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]`.

I wrote an app that used that, and it worked fine when running locally. However, when trying to certifying it for submission to the Windows Store, it failed because use of `FormatMessageA` is not allowed.

So my question is, what am I missing? Is it because I was PInvoking it? Or are certain APIs only allowed in sideloaded apps and/or for debugging purposes, but not allowed in real Windows Store Apps?

Comment: Be sure to use CharSet.Unicode in your [DllImport] declaration.

Comment: @HansPassant I take from this that you're saying the same as Alex that I should have used the Unicode version? If so, would you know where this is documented?

Comment: Just run WACK again so you'll have a fact instead of a guess.

Comment: @HansPassant Doing that now, just wanted to know if that's a rule that it should always be Unicode for Windows APIs in Windows Store Apps?

Comment: @HansPassant Btw, thanks, you and Alex were completely correct.

Comment: @HansOlsson Sir, I wanted to chat with you regarding something about API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is in the suffix "A" of FormatMessageA . "A" means ANSI encoding of text, but most modern apps use UNICODE. Try using FormatMessageW instead.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that, but I couldn't find any documentation to specify that Windows Store Apps only supports Unicode, if this is the case, do you know where it is documented?

Comment: Tried it now (using `CharSet.Unicode`) and you're right. Thanks.